# Why don't MySQL Functions work inside a function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, syntax-error

OK, this works:

```
mysql_select_db("news");

$newsarr = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC"));

echo var_dump($newsarr);
```

It returns this:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '140425-20:43:43' (length=15)
  'Date' => string '140425-20:43:43' (length=15)
  1 => string 'dfghfghdfg' (length=10)
  'Description' => string 'dfghfghdfg' (length=10)
  2 => string 'Enter text, media link or upload image' (length=38)
  'Media' => string 'Enter text, media link or upload image' (length=38)
```

This does not work:

```
function newstable()
    {
        mysql_select_db("news");

        $newsarr = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC"));

        return var_dump($newsarr);
    }

echo newstable();
```

It returns this:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

So as soon as I try to turn working code into a function it fails.  Why?  I am trying to figure out how to use these bloody MySQL functions within a function so I can have a function that builds a table out of the records in MySQL and call it at any time in any part of my webpage.  So far it is not cooperating AT ALL.

Furthermore, there are 6 records in my database so why is the array only returning the data from 1 record?

Thanks

Comment: Ask `mysql_error()` if something fails. Use a loop to fetch more than one record.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  So how come this doesn't work then:

'code'
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uName,$pWord);

function newstable()
 {
  global $con;
  global $host;
  global $uName;
  global $pWord;
  mysql_select_db("news",$con);
'code'

Comment: @AmalMurali the `mysql_*()` functions will default to the last connection opened if none is specified. It's not subject to variable scope.

Comment: @MikeW: Ah, right. Somehow I thought the OP was trying to use variables outside the function in there, but you are correct. I've removed my erroneous comment.

Comment: @wallybanger You won't like this: the `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. You shouldn't use them for new code. You should be doing this with `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Mike W, Yeah, that's what I thought!  So then why isn't this working?

Comment: @Mike W, I didn't even know mysqli was a thing.  I don't mind leaning some new stuff but will it fix my problem or do I have more fundamental issues?

Comment: @wallybanger: Separate this into a different statement: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC")`. Check for its return values and use the error handling functions. Very crude example: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC"); if($query) { /* fetcH_array here */ } else { echo mysql_error(); }`.

Comment: @wallybanger I don't know why it's not working. You should check the return value of your `mysql_query()` call, and look at `mysl_error()` for the reason. You'll need to break that statement up anyway since you need to call `mysql_fetch_array()` repeatedly to retrieve all your records.

Comment: @wallybanger `mysqli()` won't fix your code - there's something else going on. It will stop your code breaking at some point in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I did have it all separate but put it all into one function so it would be easier to post here.  Trying to keep the question simple.

Comment: Your code checks out, I've tested it. Make sure you selected the right DB and have the right DB credentials setup, plus the correct columns.

Comment: So what I'm getting from this is that I'm not necessarily doing anything wrong and I can use these mysql functions inside of a function, is that right?

Comment: @Fred, well if it's returning records when it's not in a function why would it fail to return records as soon as I put it into a function?

Comment: Is your DB connection inside the same file?

Comment: Yes, and it's also within the same <?php ?> code block.

Comment: Hard to say. Can you post your full code for it? Replacing DB credentials with `xxx`

Comment: <code>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$uName = "mike";
$pWord = "password";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uName,$pWord);

if (!$con)
 {
  $mysqlError = "<p>Can not connect to mysql: " . mysql_error() . "</p>";
  die ( "can not connect to server");
 }

function newstable()
 {
  mysql_select_db("news");
  
  $sqlgetnews = "SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC";
  
  $sqlnewsquery = mysql_query($sqlgetnews);
  
  $newsarr = mysql_fetch_array($sqlnewsquery);
  
  return var_dump($newsarr); 
 }

mysql_close($con);


echo newstable()
?>

</code>

Comment: Consult my answer below @wallybanger

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted [`in a comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306935/why-dont-mysql-functions-work-inside-a-function#comment35681559_23306935) was this:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$uName = "mike"; 
$pWord = "password"; 
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uName,$pWord); 
if (!$con) { 
$mysqlError = "<p>Can not connect to mysql: " . mysql_error() . "</p>"; 
die ( "can not connect to server"); 
}

function newstable() { 

mysql_select_db("news"); 
$sqlgetnews = "SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC"; 
$sqlnewsquery = mysql_query($sqlgetnews); 
$newsarr = mysql_fetch_array($sqlnewsquery); 
return var_dump($newsarr); } mysql_close($con); 
echo newstable()
?>
```

There is a missing semi-colon at the end of `echo newstable()`

It needs to be in there, otherwise it produced an error for me using that code.

You're also closing your DB connection prematurely.
Use the following code which tested successfully on my server:

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$uName = "mike"; 
$pWord = "password"; 
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uName,$pWord); 
if (!$con) { 
$mysqlError = "<p>Can not connect to mysql: " . mysql_error() . "</p>"; 
die ( "can not connect to server"); 
}

function newstable() { 

mysql_select_db("news"); 
$sqlgetnews = "SELECT * FROM newsByDate ORDER BY date DESC"; 
$sqlnewsquery = mysql_query($sqlgetnews); 
$newsarr = mysql_fetch_array($sqlnewsquery); 
return var_dump($newsarr); } 
echo newstable();
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Place error reporting at the beginning of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php**

Also use: (just before closing DB connection)

```
echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con) . "\n";
```

Yet, I suspect you may be trying to fetch data and to be echo'ed. If that is the case and you're trying to use something like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsarr)) // <- incorrect variable used
 {
        $row = $row["column"];
 }

 echo $row;
```

you would need to use the `$sqlnewsquery` variable.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlnewsquery)) 
 {
        $row = $row["column"];
 }

 echo $row;
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Shoudnt there be a connection in that function?

Comment: No. Read [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306935/why-dont-mysql-functions-work-inside-a-function/23312608?noredirect=1#comment35681202_23306935) @Mihai OP is using `mysql_` and not `mysqli_`

Comment: Thanks Fred, I appreciate the help :)  I will try all that and I'm also reading up on these mysql functions as I may not be fully understanding what they are doing and how the arrays work in PHP.